# Getting Error 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#

```
public float[] HitungFitness()
{
    float[] fitness = new float[populasi];
    for (var individu = 0; individu < populasi; individu++)
    {
        fitness[individu] = CekConstraint(individu);
    }
    string[] sort = new string[populasi];
    for (int i = 0; i < populasi; i++)
    {
        sort[i] = string.Format("\nIndividu {0} :Fitness {1}",(i + 1), fitness[i]);
    }
        bool swapped = true;
        while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < populasi-1 ; i++)
            {
                string[] strI = sort[i].Split('.');
                float fitI = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strI[1]));

                string[] strJ = sort[i + 1].Split('.');
                float fitJ = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strJ[1]));

                if (fitI < fitJ)
                {
                    string sTmp = sort[i];
                    sort[i] = sort[i + 1];
                    sort[i + 1] = sTmp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    return fitness;
}
```

variable populasi assign = 12

A function CekConstraint is giving a return value between '0.***' to '1'

I have a problem with:

```
float fitI = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strI[1]));
```

or

```
float fitJ = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strI[1]));
```

When the `strI` or `strJ` just giving one value of array like `strJ[1]` or `stri[1]` then I'm getting the Index was outside bounds of the array. I recognize the error but how do I fix this?

Please help me.

Comment: I guess the problem is your split should be by `:` instead of `.`, so change this `sort[i].Split('.');` into this `sort[i].Split(':');`

Comment: The only scenario where an element of the sort[] array would contain a "." is in the decimal point of the fitness[] element you write in it. When you call **strI[1]** you divide the sort[] element by "." and retrieve the second element, thus you would retrieve the decimal part of the fitness[] element contained in it, but if this one had no decimal point, a "." would not be present, and thus neither would **strI[]** contain more than one element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because it is not getting value in `strI[1]` or `strJ[1]`. It may have happened because of a `"."` is not found in `sort[i]`. Hence we can see put a condition based on `strI` and `strJ` array Length.

Change your inner for loop as

```
for (int i = 0; i < populasi-1 ; i++)
{
    float fitI = 0.0;
    float fitJ = 0.0;
    string[] strI = sort[i].Split('.');
    if(strI.Length > 1)
        fitI = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strI[1]));


    string[] strJ = sort[i + 1].Split('.');

    if(strJ.Length > 1)
        fitJ = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strJ[1]));


    if (fitI < fitJ)
    {
        string sTmp = sort[i];
        sort[i] = sort[i + 1];
        sort[i + 1] = sTmp;
        swapped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are Welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] strI = sort[i].Split('.');
float fitI = float.Parse(string.Format("0.{0}", strI[1]));
```

`sort[i]` string doesn't have `.` in it. Because of that when you call `Split('.')` you produce only array with 1 item. Because of that on `strI[1]` you receive and exception, there is no second elements in strI array.

Answer (score -3):

Why so many loops, use a list or dictinary in place or array and use foreach loop to avoid the out-of-range exception.

```
float[] fitness = new float[populasi];
//create a list for this

string[] sort = new string[populasi];
//another list 
and do foreach looping
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but rather a suggestion for optimizing the code. It should rather be a comment to the original question.